# Rectangle2D.contains() not working?

Tags: java, awt

```
new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 2, 4, 2).contains(1, 1)
```

This gives me false. Why? The point should be inside of the rectangle. Maybe I'm tired and it's probably trivial, but I don't get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You specified:

```
new Rectangle2D.Double(
    0, //x
    2, //y
    4, //width
    2  //height
);
```

So, the rectangle will begin at `0,2` and extend to `4,4`. `1,1` is outside the rectangle, as the `contains` method is not relative to the rectangle starting position, but it's based on the absolute coordinates space.

[image]

Comment: Why does the Javadoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.Double.html) say that x and y define the "upper left corner"? I can understand the askers confusion, because the way you describe the class works it looks like the "lower left corner" to me.

Comment: @911DidBush Actually my image was generic, showing that geometrically the point was out of the rectangle. But you are right, for clarity I changed the image to reflect the actual coordinate system.è

Comment: @BackSlash make a note in your answer, that the "contains" function is not relative to the rectangle starting position, but for absolute coordinate space, because it is not written in javadocs as far I searched trough it.

Comment: It took time to realize, but now I remember, that java.awt.geom uses the upper-left corner of the screen for the reference point. It would make more sense, if it was the center, so you had a Descartes coordinate system.

Comment: @ÁdámBozzay Actually, the coordinates system has nothing to do with this. A point with coordinates `1,1` will always be out of a rectangle which starts at `0,2` and ends at `4,4`, no matter what coordinates system you choose.

Comment: Yes, but in which direction the rectangle expands, does matter.

Comment: @ÁdámBozzay Yes, but this was not your question. Your question was about geometry, and it can be applied to every coordinates system, your point will always be out of that rectangle. The expansion direction has nothing to do with your issue. And by the way it's not really java, it is a standard in computer graphics. Java is just standard-compliant in this case. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/83570/why-is-the-origin-in-computer-graphics-coordinates-at-the-top-left

Comment: No, you need to convert the absolute coordinates to the Rectangle2D relative coordinates, or otherwise. And if this is correct, then yes, geometry applies here, too.
But it's too complicated for me to convert between Descartes and this, so I used the third party Poligon2D class, which can work with absolute cords.

Comment: @ÁdámBozzay I'm not getting it. What do you mean by "absolute coords"? You are already working with absolute coords. And Descartes works the same way: if you have a `4x2` rectangle which starts at `0,2`, `1,1` will be outside the rectangle.

Comment: In Descartes there is no "starts at".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135674/discussion-between-adam-bozzay-and-backslash).

Answer (score 2):

```
Rectangle2D.Double(double x, double y, double w, double h)
```

means that you place the rectangle in Point `(0,2)` and it extends from there. So it covers not `(1,1)` because at y it begins at `2`.

Comment: Maybe it should be made obvious, that the "contains" function is for absolute coordinate space, and not relative